# Show action bar and Up navigation - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I already implemented material theme and scroll-able tab in my app. Currently the Up navigation in my app is working but the Action bar is not visible. I am using the below theme,

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>       
    </style>
```

Now my app have the Up navigation like below image,

[image]

I want to show the action bar, Up navigation and Tab.I want it like the below image,

[image]

Is it possible to do it in android.

Comment: What do you call the bar that contains the Up arrow, title and skip action?

Comment: What about setting `windowActionBar` to `true`?

Comment: two action bar looks so scary

Comment: it's possible, you have to use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html but it's not advisable as it's a bad pattern and a UX horror to have 2 bars.

Comment: you can, using toolbar

Comment: @Rami windowActionBar to true doesn't show the actionbar

Comment: @Budius can you show me a tutorial link or sample so that i can learn it and do this.

Comment: I gave the link. It's a normal `View` object and you put it on your layout. On this blog post they announced the toolbar: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest.xml file, find the activity for which you want to add the action bar and add these lines

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    ....
>
```

or you can use RelativeLayout at top with background color, if you want custom Action bar.